# JPA SQL Server No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Iam writing a native query like

```
Query query = 
  entityManagerUtil.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("SELECT c.NodeID,c.Code,c.Name FROM COM_Location c");    
query.getResultList();
```

but it is not working for me....

Iam using JPA , MSSQL Server 2008 with Spring.It is working fine when i try to write JPA queries with pojo classes but it is failing to execute native queries.

My configurations in `persistance.xml` goes like this

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
```

Any one suggest me to fix the issuee

My stack trace says...

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    at com.iconma.carz.daoimpl.SecurityDaoImpl.getAllLocations(SecurityDaoImpl.java:40)
    at com.iconma.carz.serviceimpl.SecurityServiceImpl.getAllLocations(SecurityServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.iconma.carz.controllers.SecurityController.getLocations(SecurityController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: post complete stacktrace of error

Comment: Maybe you should try `SQLServer2008Dialect` instead as `SQLServerDialect` is for SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Chaitanya hi chaitanya,i edited my post with total stack trace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i even tried it by changing the dialect to 2008 but it is not working...

Answer (score 26):

First you have to define what is your dialect class name that you want to use:
in hibernate.cfg.xml add your own class address

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">com.nhl.dao.SQlServerDBDialect</property>
```

then create new class same below

```
package com.nhl.dao;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class SQlServerDBDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public SQlServerDBDialect() {
        super();
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.CHARACTER.getName()); 
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, 1, StandardBasicTypes.CHARACTER.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, 255, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGNVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.TEXT.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCLOB, StandardBasicTypes.CLOB.getName());

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the actual FIX for this issue all over your code without having to cast your query columns data type. By extending the Hibernate dialect to map the apropiate data types will no longer require cast-based workarounds. +1

Comment: Worked for me too.
Really nice solution. @user1903224 This answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: In hibernate 3, I already had a custom dialect with `registerColumnType` but needed the `registerHibernateType` in order to select `nvarchar` columns via native query. Great answer.

Answer (score 8):

The type -9 is `java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR`. Looking at the sources of the `SQLServerDialect` variants on https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect there is no mapping for nvarchar columns.

You might want to try to define your own dialect that also registers various `NVARCHAR`-like definitions:

```
public class SQLServer2008DialectWithNvarchar extends SQLServer2008Dialect {
    public SQLServer2008DialectWithNvarchar () {
        registerColumnType( Types.NCLOB, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.LONGNVARCHAR, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.NVARCHAR, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.NVARCHAR, 4000, "nvarchar($1)" );
    }
}
```

I based this on the definition for `VARCHAR` in the [`SQLServer2005Dialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2005Dialect.java). You may need to put this class in the `org.hibernate.dialect` package (or at least I seem to remember there are issues if you don't).

NOTE: I haven't actually tested this!

Comment: thanks for your quick response...i tried in this way also by putting this class as a Dialect but it doesn't worked out still

Comment: @user1903224 You are sure you are actually using this new dialect?

Comment: yes iam using that class only here is my sample

public class SQLServerDialectOverrider extends SQLServer2008Dialect {

 public SQLServerDialectOverrider() {
   super();
         registerColumnType( Types.NCLOB, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
         registerColumnType( Types.LONGNVARCHAR, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
         registerColumnType( Types.NVARCHAR, "nvarchar(MAX)" );
         registerColumnType( Types.NVARCHAR, 4000, "nvarchar($1)" );
 }
In my persistance.xml i kept this
 <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.utils.SQLServerDialectOverrider"/>

Answer (score 7):

I also face the same issue, So i do R&D and got solution as Do explicit cast like cast(t2.name as varchar), It works for me.

```
cast(t2.name as varchar)
```

Check this url.
http://www.coderanch.com/t/565413/ORM/databases/Dialect-mapping-JDBC-type

Comment: This is also a Solution but it does not seem to work always. I had even casted my ids as varchar but the issue did not go away until  I didn't use @Ebrahim Amini Sharifi Solution

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, my sql is this

```
Query nmspQuery = em.createNativeQuery("select aster from MyTable where my_column = 1001")
```

The datatype for PRODUCT_NODE_ONIX_TYPE in the Oracle 11g is nvarachar2

I fixed it by casting the value astr to to_char. 
This worked fine

```
Query nmspQuery = em.createNativeQuery("select TO_CHAR(aster) from MyTable where my_column = 1001")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend the dialect, and register the appropriate Hibernate types for the N* JDBC types, in the constructor:

```
public class MyDialect extends SomeOfTheProvidedDialects {

    public MyDialect() {
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.CHARACTER.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, 1, StandardBasicTypes.CHARACTER.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, 255, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.LONGNVARCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.TEXT.getName());
        registerHibernateType(Types.NCLOB, StandardBasicTypes.CLOB.getName());
    }
}
```

Tested, works fine.

They should have added these to the Hibernate source code already (in the org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect class)...

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to nvarchar, so when when you create query just convert the nvarchar to varchar by casting it like cast(c.name as varchar) as name.
and your issue will be resolved.