# Exception: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is my Dao function

```
public List<MerchantTransaction> merchantList(String strMerchantId, String strStatus){
        List<MerchantTransaction> merTra = null;
        Session session = null;

        try {
             session  = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             merTra = (List<MerchantTransaction>) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MERCHANT_TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTIONMERCHANTID='"+strMerchantId+"' AND TRANSACTIONSTATUS='"+strStatus+"'").list();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in Merchant traans dao list :"+e.getMessage());
            }

    return merTra;
    }
}
```

Error code-No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Here i am try to fetch a list from Database using createSQLQuery statement.I am confused in getting list of MerchantTransaction using createSQLQuery. Can anyone  help me to solve this issue.

Comment: instead of  System.out.println("Exception in Merchant traans dao list :"+e.getMessage()); do this  System.out.println(e); this would provide more helpful output/stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no mapping for NVARCHAR column.

But you can add cast to your query

```
SELECT cast(the_nvarchar_column_name as varchar) ...
```

See [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/565413/ORM/databases/Dialect-mapping-JDBC-type)

Or there are suggestions to add the mapping described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039300/jpa-sql-server-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)

Answer (score 0):

Apart of @StanislavL answer there is an error in your code. You can't get `List<MerchantTransaction>` with native SQL. 
Your query should be

```
   List<Object[]> merTra = (List<Object[]>) session.createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM MERCHANT_TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTIONMERCHANTID='" + strMerchantId
                    + "' AND TRANSACTIONSTATUS='" + strStatus + "'").list();
```

It is a bad practice to create SQL query string by strings concatenation. You should use [Parameters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930).

But the best way is using HQL. Your query is pretty simply so in HQL it can be something like this (in assumption, that MerchantTransaction has an association to Merchant)

```
from MerchantTransaction t where t.merchant.id = :merchantId 
    and t.transactionStatus = :status
```

You can use a criteria query too.