# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -151

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an issue

This are my project dependencies:

```
org.springframework.boot<spring-boot-starter-data-jpa>

org.eclipse.persistence <eclipselink>
```

To fix the problem, I configurated a class

```
public class SqlServerDialect extends SQLServer2008Dialect  {  
    public SqlServerDialect() {   
        super();  
        registerHibernateType(-151, org.hibernate.type.TimestampType.INSTANCE.getName());
    }   
}
```

Then I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -151
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
    at com.lilanz.microservice.common.tools.NativeQuery.getResultList(NativeQuery.java:56)
    at com.lilanz.microservice.common.tools.NativeQuery.sqlServerSearch(NativeQuery.java:86)
    at com.lilanz.microservice.common.tools.NativeQuery.sqlServerSearch(NativeQuery.java:90)
    at com.lilanz.microservice.common.Test.main(Test.java:41)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -151
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:666)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    ... 4 more
```

Can you help me understand what is the error -151 (java.sql.Types)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA SQL Server No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039300/jpa-sql-server-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)

Comment: there is NO value like -151 in java.sql.Types. Types.TIMESTAMP = 93. From where did you get this -151 that you are registering?