# Native query issue with function call convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "select convert(nvarchar, decryptbypassphrase(:passPhrase,tpci_password)) from trading_partner_connection_info where trading_partner_connection_id=:tpciId", nativeQuery = true)
public List<String> decrypConnectionPassword(@Param("tpciId") Integer tpciId, @Param("passPhrase") String passPhrase);
```

showing below error

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Comment: This might have been asked before e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039300/jpa-sql-server-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9 - please say how your query is different to all the other times this particular error message has been asked about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA SQL Server No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039300/jpa-sql-server-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)