# How to fetch non English character data from database using native query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot and JPA. I have table in which non English characters are stored and its datatype is nvharchar in database. Whenever I fetch data using native query from JPA I got exception in non English characters.

**This is my simple sql query**

select name from SAVINGGROUPMEM  where GROUPCD = 2118

**whenever i call it from JPA i got exception like**

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

**So after that[image] I am trying to convert nvarchar data into varchar then after I fetch it**

select cast(name as varchar(100)) from SAVINGGROUPMEM  where GROUPCD = 2118

**but I am getting ?????? instead of real data.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA SQL Server No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039300/jpa-sql-server-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-9)

Comment: What is the column type of table? If it is nvarchar then you dont to convert explicitly.

Comment: Yes column type is nvarchar.

Comment: Then how to I solve it ?